# Expand delimited columns to dynamic values in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have some data in an interesting format.  It's like this:

```
ID    Name    Info
1     Joe     quality=82,activity=23,age:rank:foo,21:0/1:30
2     Bob     activity=32,age:foo,22:31,quality=43
3     Mary    foo:age:rank,24:23:1/1,quality=62,activity=14
```

what I'm trying to extract are the age:rank:foo data which is represented as:

```
age:rank:foo,(age value):(rank value):(foo value)
```

For every record they may or may not have some or all of those keys/values and they may be in any order.  I'm trying to convert the data so I get the following:

```
ID    Name    Quality  Age    Rank    Foo
1     Joe     82       21     0/1     30
2     Bob     43       22     NULL    31
3     Mary    62       23     1/1     24
```

For getting the quality I'm doing something like this:

```
A = LOAD '...' ...;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ID, Name, REGEX_EXTRACT(info, 'quality=([0-9]+),', 1) AS Quality;
```

But I have no idea how to convert the strange nonuniform key/value map into columns.  Any suggestions? (And no I can't get them to send me the data in a better format :P )

Comment: Why can't you just keep using `REGEX_EXTRACT` or `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`? That's what I'd do.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus I don't think it's possible because the keys change places for example for one file it might be age:rank:foo,1:2:3 but the next one it might be rank:age:foo,2:1:3. Unless I'm over thinking it...

Comment: There's probably some black magic you can work with regexes to get what you want, possibly using a few different ones. But the most readable way would be to write a UDF. If you really want to stay within Pig, you could try tagging the question with `regex` and emphasizing that aspect of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEX_EXTRACT`/`REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` for this, but it's cumbersome. Since there can be one to three age/rank/foo fields in any order, you need 6 regexes for instances with all 3 fields to cover all permutations, another 6 for instances with 2 fields, and 3 more for a single field.

You get 11 fields each for age/rank/foo from this (6 from the 3-field extractions, 4 from the 2-field extractions, 1 from the single field extraction). For each of age/rank/foo, pick the one that is non-null as your result (e.g. `(foo1 is not null ? foo1 : (foo2 is not null ? foo2 : (foo3 is not null ? foo3 : ... ))) as foo_final`).